# Having trouble with div with 100% height

Tags: css, html, height

I am having a strange problem with CSS 100% height. The site of my site is as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get container to have a minimum height of 100% so my CSS is as follows:

```
html { min-height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; }
#container { height: 100%; }
```

The problem is, `#container` does not fill 100% of the height and only expands according to how much content is in `#header` and `#content`, and if `#header` and `#content` are empty or removed, `#container` does not expand at all.

I feel like I have to be overlooking something very simple, but have been looking at this forever and am at a dead end! Can someone point out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Percentage Heights**:
To set a percentage height to `#container`, its parent elements must have a specific height. In this case, the specific effect you want can be accomplished using either `height:100%` or `min-height:100%`. To achieve either of these, every ancestor of `#container` must have a height or min-height of 100%.

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

OR

```
html, body, #container {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gMKLN/)

---

**Using `min-height` vs. `height`**: Within the narrow scope of your question, they will have the same effect. But on a page that has both a height and min-height:

- If min-height is greater than height (whether specified or unspecified), the min-height will be used.
- If height is greater than min-height (whether specified or unspecified), the height will be used.

If there is a max-height specified (e.g. `#container { max-height: 50px }`) this would overrule height. However, max-height cannot overrule min-height. [Read more at this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights).

*NOTE:* [`min-height` is not supported by some versions of Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh).

Comment: HockeyRef45 also wants a minimum height of 100% on the `#container` so that it will expand with its content.

Comment: @Neil: Edited my answer to address that.